# Deploying GitLab Reference Architecture on AWS with GET

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gitlab, terraform-provider-aws

Im trying to complete the implementation course in the Gitlab PSE pathway.

I already did all the setup of the enviroment, configuring the necessary files, im at the step of Running a Toolkit (GET) Docker Container.

After positioning myself at the appropiate folder :

cd /gitlab-environment-toolkit/terraform/environments/3k

I can run terraform init

and it runs succesfully

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rddw7.jpg)

but after running

terraform plan -out 3k.aws_ec2.tfplan

it gives me an error

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok4U0.jpg)

my main.tf looks like this

```
terraform {
    required_providers {
        aws = {
        source = "hashicorp/aws"
        }
    }
}

# Configure the AWS Provider
provider "aws" {
    region = var.region
}
```

And i already set the enviroment variables on the linux instance

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnhE5.jpg)

And running the command :

```
docker run -it  \
-v /home/ec2-user/gitlab-environment-toolkit/keys:/gitlab-environment-toolkit/keys \
-v /home/ec2-user/gitlab-environment-toolkit/ansible/environments/3k:/gitlab-environment-toolkit/ansible/environments/3k \
-v /home/ec2-user/gitlab-environment-toolkit/ansible/ansible.cfg:/gitlab-environment-toolkit/ansible/ansible.cfg \
-v /home/ec2-user/gitlab-environment-toolkit/terraform/environments/3k:/gitlab-environment-toolkit/terraform/environments/3k \
-e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID \
-e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY \
-e GITLAB_PASSWORD=$GITLAB_PASSWORD \
registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-environment-toolkit:latest
```

I pass the values to those variables and use them in the Docker image, but it gives me the error shown above.

I want to make sure that im using the correct keys from AWS, im using them from this screen :

[Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYzJv.jpg)

i heard that you could use them from here as well but i don’t have access :

[Image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQU5J.jpg)

Can anyone help me? after running terraform i only need to run the ansible scripts and would complete the workshop, im so close but can’t figure out the terraform error, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

I tried modifying the main.tf file, with hardcoded AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, i also tried to change the Region from the different setup files from Terraform variables.tf and enviroment.tf

I think one of the possible problems is that im not getting the correct keys from AWS due to my lack of access to the IAM screen i showed earlier, the keys i get show that those are temporary credentials, but still i use them very quickly from when i log in to aws and execute the commands.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was indeed on the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY , AWS is very nitpicky about security, so we had to make some changes to policies and roles in order to make it work, it was a hassle but we managed to continue after that, thanks.